# Loading dependent entities without navigation property

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to load all dependent entities for a given entity. The entity types (and thereby the model) is not kown at compile time. My first try was to use the `Collections` property:

```
foreach (var collection in context.Entry(someEntity).Collections)
{
   collection.Load();
}
```

This works fine when the entity has a navigation property defined. But not every entity has. Therefore, I am looking for a way to load the dependent entities based on foreign keys:

```
foreach (var fk in context.Entry(someEntity).Metadata.GetReferencingForeignKeys())
{
   //now what?
}
```

Of course a solution does not have to rely on the foreign key, it was just my first attempt.

Comment: EF.Core is given for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using reflection:**

I made a helper class. `Load<T>` does the querying using the generic `Set<T>` and a filter for the foreign key property (works with shadow properties too).

`LoadDependentEntities` uses reflection to create a generic method info of Load` using the type known by the foreign key.

Restriction: This expects the foreign key to be a single property of type Guid.

```
class Loader
{
    public Task LoadDependentEntities(DbContext context, Guid principalId, IForeignKey foreignKey)
    {
        var methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Load), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(foreignKey.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType);
        string foreignKeyName = foreignKey.Properties.First().Name;
        return (Task)genericMethodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { context, principalId, foreignKeyName });
    }
    
    private async Task Load<T>(DbContext context, Guid principalId, string foreignKeyName) where T : class
    {
        await context.Set<T>()
            .Where(p => EF.Property<Guid>(p, foreignKeyName) == principalId)
            .LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
var loader = new Loader();
foreach (var fk in context.Entry(someEntity).Metadata.GetReferencingForeignKeys())
{
    await loader.LoadDependentEntities(context, someEntity.Id, fk);
}
```